# How to disable a specific row to be draggable in AG table?

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using the [`Managed Dragging`](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-dragging/#managed-dragging) of AG Grid React table and want to disable a specific row, if it matches the condition. 
In `Docs` I couldn't find enough information how to do that. As it describes [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-dragging/#enabling-row-dragging), it is possible to add the `draggable` feature conditionally, like this

```
rowDrag: params => !params.node.group
```

In `params` object, I couldn't find the `row data` to implement my condition. 
In the code example described below, I want to disable the row to be draggable if the `name==='John`.
Also, how to that if you have row draggable for entire row: `rowDragEntireRow={true}`? 
[Sandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/preventrowdrag-smi202?file=/src/App.js) and code

```
import React from "react";
import { AgGridReact } from "ag-grid-react";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-grid.css";
import "ag-grid-community/dist/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css";
function App() {
  const [gridApi, setGridApi] = React.useState(null);
  const [gridColumnApi, setGridColumnApi] = React.useState(null);

  const onGridReady = (params) => {
    setGridApi(params.api);
    setGridColumnApi(params.columnApi);
  };

  const defaultColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    editable: true
  };

  const columnDefs = [
    {
      headerName: "Name",
      field: "name",
      rowDrag: (params) => {
        console.log("params", params);
        return !params.node.group;
      }
    },
    { headerName: "stop", field: "stop" },
    {
      headerName: "duration",
      field: "duration"
    }
  ];

  const rowData = React.useMemo(
    () => [
      {
        name: "John",
        stop: 10,
        duration: 5
      },
      {
        name: "David",
        stop: 15,
        duration: 8
      },
      {
        name: "Dan",
        stop: 20,
        duration: 6
      }
    ],
    []
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 align="center">React-App</h1>

      <div>
        <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: "700px" }}>
          <AgGridReact
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            rowData={rowData}
            defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
            rowDragManaged={true}
            //rowDragEntireRow={true}
          ></AgGridReact>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Update your `rowDrag` definition in the `name` column definition to the following:

```
  rowDrag: (params) => {
    if (params.data.name == "John") {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/preventrowdrag-forked-6x2kkz?file=/src/App.js).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this works fine, could you also give me an idea how to do the same  when "rowDragEntireRow={true}" is activated and I don't have an access to params?

Comment: it should work exactly the same. Check the demo link I provided where `rowDragEntireRow` is enabled.

Comment: this works great, but when you have only "rowDragEntireRow={true}" and no "rowDrag" in "columnDefs",  how to deal with that? 
See the link, please. https://codesandbox.io/s/preventrowdrag-forked-lmyddd?file=/src/App.js.
I mean in case you don't want to have the draggable icon in any row like in the link above.